# Parse already loaded data by back-end in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's possible to parse already loaded data in HTML (eg. by back-end) in Angular.JS without reload them using AJAX or place data as JSON in JS variable? I want to avoid the effect of double load and empty page before Angular is ready to use.

For example my code:

```
<div class="ngPreloaded"> 
    <!-- Data loaded with HTTP Response -->
    <div class="content">Foo <strong>Bar</strong></div> 
    <div class="content">Foo #2 <strong>Bar #2</strong></div> 
</div>
<div class="content" ng-repeat="data in mydata">
    {{ data.first }} <strong>{{ data.second }}</strong>
</div>
```

And later I can use them just like elements loaded by Angular, eg. filters, scopes and more. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use ng-bind directive in preloaded html https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: You could write html parser to convert to scope data right in the `$http` success callback and let angular do the rendering based on that new data. A more detailed explanation of your needs would help

Comment: I'm using Angular to show 'cards' with user's message, votes and comments (but it isn't preloaded like cards), something like facebook posts. I want preload the first 6 cards and the more can be loaded dynamically using AJAX. All of them can be filtered using Angular.